# How to delete a selected row of a table created in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="metric_results">

    <div id="form">
        <form name="myForm"  >
        ...//get course IDnumber and course score
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="table">
    <table id="TABLE" border = '1'>


    </table>
    </div>



 <script type="text/javascript">
    //when click on "add" button,call "addTable" function.
    document.getElementById("add_button").onclick = function() {addTable()};
    document.getElementById("delete_button").onclick = function() {DeleteTableRow()};

    var stock = new Array();
    var i = 0;

    function addTable() {  //create table with 3 column(idnumber,score,checkbox)


        var c = document.createElement("INPUT");
        c.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        stock[i] = new Array(id, score);//id= course ID number,score=course score, get from form

        //Create table row and append it to end of table
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                var td = document.createElement('TD');
                if(j == 2){
                    td.setAttribute("id","check_box"+(i+1));
                    td.appendChild(c);}
                else{
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stock[i][j]));}
                tr.appendChild(td);
                }
        table.appendChild(tr);

        i=i+1
    }

// Delete courses that their checkbox is on.
    function DeleteTableRow(){
    var check_boxes=new Array();
    for(j=0; j<i ;j++){
    check_boxes[j]= document.getElementById("check_box"+(j+1));
    if(check_boxes[j].checked==true){document.getElementById("TABLE").deleteRow(j+1);}      
    }
</script>
</body>
```

I create a form which get course idnumber and course score.At first, when I fill the form, javascript creates a table so when I click the "add" button, I can add courses. Now, I want to add another function named `DeleteTableRow()` to delete the selected rows.

When I create the table for each course,I create a checkbox column and set "id" for each rows `checkbox(td.setAttribute("id","check_box"+(i+1));)` so in the `DeleteTableRow()` function I use `getElementById("check_box"+(j+1))` in the for loop.

Everything is OK but I can't check the value of the check box and I can't delete the selected rows. what should I do and how do I check it?

Comment: Far too much code, sorry. Cut it down to a minimal example.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman.I cut it down.I hope it's readable.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that in your addTable function you set the `id` attribute on the table cell, rather than the checkbox. Naturally, cells don't have a checked attribute. You could fix this by doing the `setAttribute('id', ...)` on `c`, before the loop.

Note there are a few strange things about your code - for example, you should really use the literal `[]` when defining a new array, rather than the `new Array()` call; but having said that there doesn't seem to be any need for the `check_boxes` array in the first place, since you never use it.

In any case, your code would be a lot simpler if you used something like jQuery, which is pretty much the default for doing DOM manipulation in Javascript these days.

Comment: thanks alot,I don't know JQuery well,But I try to learn it and use it. thanks for your attention.